# Toggle infinite loop by the same key

Tags: autohotkey

I want to be able to press key and run an infinite loop, and be able to press the same key to stop the loop. In a simple case I want the script to click indefinitely:

```
XButton2::
if (Doing = 0)
{
  Doing := 1
  While Doing = 1
  {
     Click
  }
  return
} else {
 Doing := 0
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work - `XButton2` does not respond any more because it is running a script. I can switch `Doing := 0` by other key but I want for it to be the same `XButton2`. Any simple way of doing this? I would avoid complicated solutions.

Comment: your code looks fancy :D try using `setTimer` instead

Comment: @Blauhirn I am not AHK pro, just using it for a few very simple things :) This looks interesting, thanks, I'll have a look at subroutines - this might solve the problem

Comment: @Blauhim Thanks, that did it. If you could write this as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: yeah I was lazy. could've spared you the research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [timed subroutine](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm). That's how you'd start/stop a loop in ahk usually.

For example:

```
clicking := false

label_click:
    click
return

XButton2::
    clicking := !clicking
    if(clicking)
        setTimer, label_click, 1 ; click once every millisecond (approx.)
    else
        setTimer, label_click, off
return
```

That is how I usually do it, though I'd love to see a more compact version.